# Angular animation to bottom with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am very new to angular and I am trying to find a way to do an animation similar to this:

```
  var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById('#entries'));
  elm.animate({"bottom":"0"}, "slow");
```

I want to add this on a click event. So I have this

```
 <span class="close" ng-click="close()">Close</span>
```

And on my controller I have:

```
  $scope.close = function() {
       var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById('#entries'));
       elm.animate({"bottom":"0"}, "slow");  
  }
```

but this is not working. Is there a way to do an animation like this with javascript?

I have two divs on the same page

```
 <div id="entries"></div>
 <div id="views"></div>
```

and I want them to have different animations. So I tried to do the animation with css but is not working. It animates only the first div.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be sure to give position for that, otherwise bottom value won't be affected...

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this directive, but if you already use Angular 1.3, could this help you https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to get the element in a wrong way. You should have:
`var el = document.getElementById('entries');` (without the hash sign)

Anyway, I would use Angular's jQuery by injecting '$' to your controller:
`var el = $('#entries');`

Answer (score -1):

```
var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById('#entries'));
```

which always animates the first because you have clearly mentioned in your code that animate firstone only, dont use document.getElementById, which gets single DOM element